# Primarily opinion based error

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Why was my question closed as [primarily opinion based](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284922/what-is-a-sa-mgr) ?

> ## What is a Sa Mgr.?
>
> I read some (software engineers) linkedIn profiles where they have "Sa
> Mgr." as current job role.
>
> What is a "Sa Mgr." ? I suppose Mgr stands for "manager" but I have no
> idea on what "Sa" stands for.

This is definitely wrong

Comment: Hi Albert.  For those of us who can't see deleted questions, could you please quote your original question?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking what constitutes a "Sa Mgr." or are you asking what the abbreviation "Sa" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it wrong?

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

We aren't necessarily experts in the terminology of a particular region, industry, or company. Therefore, we can share our thoughts or opinions, but may not be able to find facts or references to support our claims. I suppose the "too broad" reason would have also worked for the same reasons.

Either way, it's not a suitable question for a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Hi Thomas, if you don't know the answer I suppose you should **not** answer at all. "I don't know the answer" doesn't automatically turn into "I give you my opinion and thus your question is opinion based". This is madness.

Comment: @Albert It's not that I don't know the answer, but that I know that job titles vary by region, industry, and company. Without that information, it's not an answerable question. With that information, it isn't valuable to other people. Both make it a question that isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that job titles could vary by region/industry/etc. Thanks

Comment: I have seen job titles vary between multiple companies on the same _street_. The general idea of junior < regular < senior < manager etc holds but the specifics do vary.

Comment: If the reason that it was considered "opinion-based" was not given IN the comments of the question, then that's definitely a problem; no discussion. The fact that he had to ask about it indicates something's wrong, because without any viewpoints of "everything varies" the source of opinion disparity is in no way clear.

Comment: All uses of language vary (to some degree) by region, industry, etc., but that does not make them "primarily opinion-based".   I'm not saying this question is a good fit for SE, but this is most definitely *not* a matter of opinion, it is a matter of *convention*.